# Calendar - edit script

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible that the calendar start on monday?
I have found this in a tutorial but my JS knowledge isn't enougth.
I changed some values but no success.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Calendar(id, year, month) { 
  var elem = document.getElementById(id)

  var mon = month - 1  // (1)
  var d = new Date(year, mon)

  var table = ['<table><tr>']

  // (2) fill first row 
  //  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
  // 29 30 31| 1  2  3  4  
  for (var i=0; i<d.getDay(); i++) {
    table.push('<td></td>')
  }

  // main body (3)
  while(d.getMonth() == mon) {
    table.push('<td>'+d.getDate()+'</td>')

    if (d.getDay() % 7 == 6) {   // (4)
      table.push('</tr><tr>')
    }

    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)  
  }

  // (5) table tail
  for (var i=d.getDay(); i<7; i++) {
    table.push('<td></td>')
  }

  table.push('</tr></table>')

  elem.innerHTML = table.join('\n')
}
new Calendar("cal", 2015, 9)
</script>
```

Comment: Which calendar plug-in ou are using ?

Comment: use no plugin... pure javavscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row's column needs to be shifted left and the row breaks set to '0' (Sunday).

```
     var firstRow_col = (d.getDay() + 6) % 7;
     for (var i=0; i<firstRow_col; i++) {
         table.push('<td></td>')
     }

      ...

     if (d.getDay() % 7 == 0) {   // (4)
          table.push('</tr><tr>')
     }
```

EDIT: Realized that the tail needs to be cleaned too if the table style becomes visible.

For example:

```
    if (d.getDay() !== 0)  {
         for (var i=0; i < 8 - d.getDay(); i++) {
             table.push('<td></td>')
         }
    }
```

See full code and demo:

```js
     function Calendar(id, year, month) {
       var elem = document.getElementById(id)

       var mon = month - 1 // (1)
       var d = new Date(year, mon)

       var table = ['<table><tr>']

       // (2) fill first row 
       //  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
       // 29 30 31| 1  2  3  4  
       //   for (var i=0; i<d.getDay(); i++) {
       var firstRow_col = (d.getDay() + 6) % 7;
       for (var i = 0; i < firstRow_col; i++) {
         table.push('<td></td>')
       }

       // main body (3)
       while (d.getMonth() == mon) {
         table.push('<td>' + d.getDate() + '</td>')

         // if (d.getDay() % 7 == 6) {   // (4)
         if (d.getDay() % 7 == 0) { // (4)
           table.push('</tr><tr>')
         }

         d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
       }

       // (5) table tail
       for (var i = d.getDay(); i < 7; i++) {
         table.push('<td></td>')
       }

       table.push('</tr></table>')

       elem.innerHTML = table.join('\n')
     }
     new Calendar("cal1", 2015, 1)
      new Calendar("cal2", 2015, 2)
      new Calendar("cal3", 2015, 3)
      new Calendar("cal4", 2015, 4)
      new Calendar("cal5", 2015, 5)
      new Calendar("cal6", 2015, 6)
      new Calendar("cal7", 2015, 7)
      new Calendar("cal8", 2015, 8)
      new Calendar("cal9", 2015, 9)
      new Calendar("cal10", 2015, 10)
      new Calendar("cal11", 2015, 11)
      new Calendar("cal12", 2015, 12)
```

```html
Jan <div id="cal1"></div><hr>
Feb <div id="cal2"></div><hr>
Mar <div id="cal3"></div><hr>
Apr <div id="cal4"></div><hr>
May <div id="cal5"></div><hr>
Jun <div id="cal6"></div><hr>
Jul <div id="cal7"></div><hr>
Aug <div id="cal8"></div><hr>
Sep <div id="cal9"></div><hr>
Oct <div id="cal10"></div><hr>
Nov <div id="cal11"></div><hr>
Dec <div id="cal12"></div><hr>
```

Comment: I did something similar.  But rather than jack the answer, I'll just show my fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/durbnpoisn/8g1k2w7x/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot 1 up for you... is it also possible to fill the empty days from last and next month. I hope you know what I mean...

Comment: @fteinz Please show that you made an effort yourself, you won't learn anything if we just hand you code.

Answer (score 0):

The function `Calendar` (which doesn't need the `new` before it unless you plan on using it as an object), takes the `year` and `month` arguments and creates a table of days for that month resembling what a US calendar would look like.

Your example input is for September 2015 which starts on a Tuesday.  If you want it to start on a Monday, then you can input a month that starts on a Monday like June 2015 (i.e. `Calendar("cal", 2015, 6);`).

The way that the function uses this bit of code to properly space the first day of the month:

```
for (var i=0; i<d.getDay(); i++) {
    table.push('<td></td>')
}
```

`d.getDay()` return the day of the week of the `Date` object `d`.  So if `d` is a Monday, `d.getDay()` returns `1`.  This bit of code adds `1` to `i` until it equals `d.getDay()` and adds an empty table cell (`"<td></td>"`) each time.

For there, it increments `d` by one day while adding table cells with the day of the month to the table, while ending the row each time it reaches the 7th day.

Edit:

Misunderstood what you meant by "start on Monday".  Like Key Lime Tartlet said, you just need to shift `d.getDay()` by -1 so that Sundays are essentially Mondays.